# Django: item extendable discount calculation

Tags: python, django, oop, e-commerce

I'm thinhking about e-shop django skeleton.

```
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    discount = models.DecimalField()


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.DecimalField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    discount = models.DecimalField()
```

Now I need to calculate product final discount. It's the biggest one of the product and category discount:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_final_discount(self):
        return max([self.discount, self.category.discount])
```

But now I need to extend my models with Brand model. Brand model has own discount, so I need to modify Product.get_final_discount() method to consider Brand's discount in final product price calculation.

Question: what is the best way to implement final product discount method that doesn't violate open-closed principle?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to extend my models with Brand model"? Do you want to add foreign key to Category, Product or both from Brand model or to Brand model? Or do you want subclass Brand model?

Comment: @VladimirDanilov I need to add FK from Product to Brand in this case. Also I want to be free to add the same FK's from Product to models with own discounts.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method that checks all of your model's fields for 2 conditions: 1.) that the field is a `ForeignKey` and 2.) that the model it references has a `discount` attribute. If both are true, the method adds the value of the `reference_model.discount` to an array of discounts. This method could then be used in your `max()` function.

Here's a working example:

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)


class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)

    def get_all_discounts(self):
        all_fields = self._meta.get_fields()
        discounts = []
        for field in all_fields:
            if field.get_internal_type() == 'ForeignKey':
                field_ref = getattr(self, field.name)
                if hasattr(field_ref, 'discount'):
                    discounts.append(field_ref.discount)

        return discounts

    def get_final_discount(self):
        return max(self.get_all_discounts())
```